# WebDriverException (Status code 127) when running Selenium + webdriver_manager on gitlab-CI machine (linux)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I'm running a simple CI pipeline on GitLab for a Selenium script headlessly + using `webdriver_manager` to handle chrome driver binary.

This part is passed:

```
Get LATEST chromedriver version for None google-chrome
There is no [linux64] chromedriver for browser None in cache
Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Driver has been saved in cache [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/100.0.4896.60]
```

But after that I'm getting this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`
```

What is the problem? Seems like webdriver_manager has a problem by running in CI.

Here is a simple script for reproduce:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.find_element('name', 'q').send_keys("Wikipedia")
```

This is one of the pipelines:
https://gitlab.com/mmonfared/test/-/jobs/2350697126

This is a sample project:
https://gitlab.com/mmonfared/test

I've also opened an issue in webdriver_manager github repo, no answers yet:

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/363

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`
```

...implies that you are executing your tests as the ***root*** user.

---

### Deep Dive

As per [**Chrome doesn't start or crashes immediately**](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start?authuser=0)

> A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as
> root user (administrator) on Linux. While it is possible to work
> around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your
> WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly
> discouraged. Please configure your environment to run Chrome as a
> regular user instead.

---

### Solution

Execute your tests as a ***non-root*** user.

Comment: So how to run test as a non-root user? After your answer I spent hours for reaching this in gitlab-ci, but I couldn't. 

Also `--no-sandbox` didn't help.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: The same error. 
This is repo: https://gitlab.com/mmonfared/test

Could you please take a look at gitlab-ci.yml and code file and tell me what should I do?